# Force included pages to be included (i.e. not opened by themselves)

Tags: php, include

I am in the process of creating my own CMS system because of I am tired of Wordpress (and the hack attempts that come with it).

My question is this: Is there any way to force pages in my includes directory to only be opened as included pages? Basically what I am looking at doing is allowing search engines to crawl my public_html/blog_files and /public_html/pages folders, but if say google displays them in searches, I want then to open that included page inside of a pre-determined page.

Typically, from my website I call the single_post.php page with a blog_abc123.php page included. If someone opens blog_abc123.php, I want it to then include itself inside of the single_post.php page and then display  the single_post.php page with blog_abc123.php in it.

I hope this is explained well, and you can understand my idea.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There are other cm available - have you tried them

Comment: I have looked at a lot of them, but de ided I would rather go back to free hand coding everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are your includes publicly accessible in the first place? You need to fix that.

In the meantime, you can use [get_included_files()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) which returns an array containing all files that have been included in the script so far. By counting the contents of this array, you can determine if the current file is being included or not (because if not, it will be the only file). Then you can redirect to the correct parent page:

```
<?php
if (count(get_included_files()) == 1) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: /the-correct-url');
    exit;
}
```

Google will see this 301 and index your site correctly.

With that said, it's odd that you would want these includes crawled in the first place. Better to use a sitemap with the correct URLs.

Comment: My normal includes (header, footer, menu, etc) are out of public_HTML. I have is individual blog entries saved as .PHP and blog pages saved as .PHP files. Take my "blog.php" file. This file includes the header.php & menu.php, then searches my blog_files directory and includes the 5 most recent blog files and includes them. Then if so.done clicks on a blog entry, it opens the single_blog.PHP file with the individual blog entry included in that. I want the single_blog.PHP page with the blog file included to be indexed by search engines and not just the individual blog file.

Comment: I guess my other question would be, is there a way to create cached copies of the completed includes files (i.e with all included content) and allow search engines to crawl these? One of my blog URLs would typically look like this: HTTPS://www.something.com/page.php?entry=post124

Comment: " individual blog entries saved as .PHP and blog pages saved as .PHP files" - I don't understand this. Aren't you using a database?

Comment: No. I wanted to move away from and database. My individual blog entries are essentially just formated text that is included into the body of other pages. Most of my stuff is how-to documents and I do not add to it very often. It is not a daily/hourly blog. The entries are essentially just very short how-to's.

Comment: I think that's a mistake. Either way, there are a great many different caching systems that can be used, with which you can set a very high expiry time. Here are a few https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_PHP_accelerators - which one you use is dependent on your requirements.

Comment: When they are cached, does it cache the entire page (I.e all the included pages together)?

Comment: If that's how you set it up, yes.

Comment: Awesome, I think that is how I will do it then. I was under the assumption that it would only cache the static pages. Thanks for your insight and help.

Answer (score 0):

My other option is to rewrite the blog entry pages to have the includes in them for header, foot, etc, but then is there any way for my main page to only include a section of that page (I.e just the body) when displaying the 5 most recent posts?